# Transform text file without delimiter with xslt to xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm searching for the right tool to transform text files into xml.

The text file looks like this:

```
2017-01-03-10.11.1201000B  H4_01DE33411121...
2017-01-01-09.12.1301000BHAX4_01DE34256137...
2017-01-01-10.12.1301000BMLH4_01DE63789221...
```

Each line is the content of an entity and I have following information:

```
Letter 0-18: Attribute1
Letter 19-21: Attribute2
Letter 22-23: Attribute3
Letter 24: Attribute4
Letter 25-31: Attribute5
and so on....
```

and so on...

Now I'm searching for a tool which transforms this text file along this rules to following xml

```
<entities>
    <entity>
        <attribute1>2017-01-03-10.11.12</attribute1>
        <attribute2>010</attribute2>
        <attribute3>00</attribute3>
        <attribute4>B</attribute4>
        <attribute5>H4_01</attribute5>
        ... and so on
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <attribute1>2017-01-01-09.12.13</attribute1>
        <attribute2>010</attribute2>
        <attribute3>00</attribute3>
        <attribute4>B</attribute4>
        <attribute5>HAX4_01</attribute5>
        ... and so on
    </entity>
   <entity>
        <attribute1>2017-01-01-10.12.13</attribute1>
        <attribute2>010</attribute2>
        <attribute3>00</attribute3>
        <attribute4>B</attribute4>
        <attribute5>MLH4_01</attribute5>
        ... and so on
    </entity>
</entities>
```

The tool needs also to implement some simple logic, for example trimming Strings, if/else, Date format conversion.

First, I thought on using xslt - so the owner of this weird text file could produce the corresponding configuration file even on his own (that would be best!). But I often read that xslt is only for converting xml to other formats, not to convert plain text files to xml.

It should also be maintainable so a shell script using awk and sed would be very confusing.

Do yo know a tool which is more suitable than xslt?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 can read in text files with `unparsed-text('file.txt')` and then use `tokenize`, `substring` and/or `xsl:analyze-string` to break up strings into parts so XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 is certainly a suitable tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart way to do this is to generate an XSLT stylesheet from a data description file that describes the input.

If the data description file has

```
<fields>
  <field name="attribute1" start="1" length="18"/>
  <field name="attribute2" start="19" length="2"/>
</fields>
```

then it's pretty easy to generate an XSLT 3.0 transformation which does

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <entities>
    <xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text-lines('input.xml')">
      <entity>
        <attribute1>{substring(., 1, 18)}</attribute1>
        <attribute2>{substring(., 1, 18)}</attribute2>
      </entity>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </entities>
</xsl:template>
```

(and generating XSLT 2.0 is only very slightly more complex, but doing XSLT 1.0 is harder because you can't read a plain text file directly).

Implementing your "simple logic" is a bit trickier, but it wouldn't be hard to add an extra field to the data description:

```
<field name="attribute1" start="1" length="18" action="checkDate"/>
```

which causes the generated XSLT to be

```
<attribute1>{f:checkDate(substring(., 1, 18))}</attribute1>
```

invoking a function in the stylesheet such as

```
<xsl:function name="f:checkDate" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="if ($in castable as xs:date) then $in else error(...)"/>
</xsl:function>
```